# Limit the actions taken from a moderator shown for flagged posts to moderators

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, flags

When a flag is raised for a post, moderators see any action taken from moderators on the question, as in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

In this case, I have edited the answer right after it was posted, not after it was flagged.

Showing a moderator edited the post before it was flagged doesn't give helpful information, as the edit could have been done:

- Even one year before the post was flagged
- Before the moderator was appointed/elected moderator
- When the post was fine, and before a successive edit done from the OP made the post not anymore acceptable

The page could show any action taken from moderators after the flag was raised; as alternative, it could show any action taken from moderators in the thirty days before the flag was raised.